# How to write tensorflow flag variables in a logger

Tags: python, tensorflow, argparse, flags

I am using tensowflow flags to parse arguments like the follows:

```
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
lags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 'Initial learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('epochs', 200, 'Number of epochs to train.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 32, 'Number of graphs in a batch.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden1', 5, 'Number of units in hidden layer 1.')
```

I want to write these arguments into a logger. I know that when using "argparse" instead of flags here, we can use the following code to write into logger:

```
logger.info(vars(args)); pprint(vars(args))
```

But when I use

```
logger.info(vars(FLAGS))
```

it shows

```
{'__wrapped': <absl.flags._flagvalues.FlagValues object at 0x11dfc1da0>}
```

in the logger, not the specific arguments. So how to deal with "flags" ?

Comment: `args` is a `argparse.Namespace` object, a simple class that stores the values as attributes.  `vars(args)` returns that `__dict__` dictionary.  Evidently `FLAGS` is a more complex class, Isn't there any help in the `tf` documentation for `FLAGS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can just drop `vars`, `logger.info(FLAGS)` can give the value of parameters.